# Required doesn't work when submitting a form through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

#### Situation

I have a form which contains a input that is required. It used to work, but ever since I submit the form with JavaScript/jQuery the required fields are not required anymore.

#### Question

How can I make input fields required when sumbitting the form with JavaScript/jQuery?

#### HTML

```
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input required name="ttlAddCategory" id="frmAddCategoryTtl" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md col-md-6" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Icon:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input name="iconAddCategory" id="frmAddCategoryIcon" placeholder="Upload uw Marker en plaats hier uw URL. Max. 70x70 Aangeraden 33x44" class="form-control input-md col-md-6" type="text" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Toevoegen" id="btnAddCategory">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a id="cke_29" class="btn btn-primary" title="Afbeelding" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_29_label" aria-haspopup="false" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(23,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(24,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(25,this);return false;">
            Upload hier
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

#### JS

```
    $('#btnAddCategory').click(function() {
        if ($('#frmAddMarkerCat').find('input[name="iconAddCategory"]').val() == '') {
            $('#frmAddMarkerCat').find('input[name="iconAddCategory"]').val('default');
        }

        $('#frmAddMarkerCat').submit();

    });
```

Comment: If you submit the form with Javascript, you have to do input validation yourself. But it doesn't look like you really need to submit with Javascript. You can change the button to a submit button, and the click handler can still fix up the `iconAddCategory` first.

Comment: I need to sumbit with Javascript because of some other code which was not neccesary to show, bu thanks anyways

Comment: You could use the jquery-validate plugin to automate JS validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If manually submitting the form does the trick then, instead of doing a `.submit()` on the form object try to replicate the manual action by triggering a click on the button you use to manually submit.

Instead of:

```
$('#formID').submit();
```

Try:

```
$('#submitButton').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You can also do `$('#submitButton').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Barmar already said: "If you submit the form with Javascript, you have to do input validation yourself."

A Simple version of you code with custom required validation would look like this:

```
var $iconAddCategory = $('#frmAddMarkerCat').find('input[name="iconAddCategory"]');

$('#btnAddCategory').click(function() {
  if ($iconAddCategory.val() === '') {
    $iconAddCategory.val('default');
  }

  validate(function() {
    $('#frmAddMarkerCat').submit(); 
  });
});


function validate(callback) {
  var emptyCount = 0;

  $("#form").find('input[required]').each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);

    if ($element.val() === '') {
      emptyCount++;
      $element.addClass('error');
    }
  });

  if (emptyCount === 0) {
    callback();
  } 
}
```

http://jsbin.com/wiwodekene/edit?html,js,output